# Ошибка в проверке оплаты на pyQiwip2p и aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, qiwi, pyqiwi

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call_query: call_query.data == 'buy')
async def buy(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
        comment = str(callback_query.from_user.id) + "_" + str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        bill = p2p.bill(amount=1, lifetime=15, comment=comment)
        url = bill.pay_url
        bill = bill.bill_id
        qiwiMenu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        btnUrlQIWI = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ссылка на оплату", url=url)
        qiwiMenu.insert(btnUrlQIWI)
        btnCheckQIWI = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Проверить оплату!", callback_data="check_")
        qiwiMenu.insert(btnCheckQIWI)
        keyboard.add(btnUrlQIWI,btnCheckQIWI)
        db.add_check(callback_query.from_user.id, bill)
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id,
                               f"Оплатите 150₽ за доступ по кнопке ниже\n \nКомментарий к оплате: {comment}",
                               reply_markup=keyboard)



@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call_query: call_query.data == 'check_')
async def top_up(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    bill = str(callback.data[6:])
    info = db.get_check(bill)
    if info != False:
        if str(p2p.check(bill_id=bill).status) == "PAID":
            user_money = db.user_money(callback.from_user.id)
            money = int(info[4])
            db.set_money(callback.from_user.id, user_money+money)
            await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Счет оплачен! Ждите пока с вами свяжется администратор")

        else:
            await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Вы не оплатили счет!", reply_markup=nav.buy_menu(False, bill=bill))
    else:
        await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Счет не найден!")
        print(p2p.check(bill_id=bill).status)
```

После нажатия на кнопку бот отправляет мне 'Счет не найден', хотя status = WAITING и в строке кода вылезает ошибка **ValueError: Code: 404. Qiwi response is not JSON. This is Qiwi-side bug.**

Comment: чему равен `callback.data[6:]`? должен быть bill ID, но чет не похоже. проверь его

Comment: Я если честно не знаю, можете подсказать решение которое по вашему мнению подойдет мне? По идее данная переменная удаляет первые 6 символов из bill_id @SeniorPomidor

Comment: ну так выводите в лог и посмотрите результат

Comment: @SeniorPomidor  а как это сделать если не секрет?

Comment: println(callback.data[6:])

Comment: Не получается, просто выводит ошибку киви и все

Comment: Починил, выводит check_

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, не знаешь как это можно починить?

Comment: надо начать с того, чтобы вывести весь `callback.data` и посмотреть что там. может вы неправильно id берете

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Я починил, спасибо что обратили внимание на это. Я глобализировал переменную bill из первой функции